# Proof that $x\arctan x > \frac{\pi}{2}x-1$, for $x\geq 0$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I've a problem with proving the following inequality:
$x\arctan x  > \frac{\pi}{2}x-1$, for $x\geq 0$.

I can see that it is true for $x=0$ or $x=\infty$, but I cannot prove it for other values.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: $x\arctan x = x\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \arctan \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$ for $x>0$. Can you continue?

Comment: Well because it is not true. What's true however is that $\arctan(1/x)<1/x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks.

Comment: @Gary But how to prove the following: $\arctan(1/x)<1/x$ ???

Comment: Show by differentiation that $\arctan(w)-w$ is monotonically decreasing for $w\geq 0$. Then $\arctan(w)-w<\arctan(0)-0=0$ for $w>0$, i.e., $\arctan(w)<w$ for $w>0$. Apply this with $w=1/x$.